# bash shell-How to swift a file specific content with another file after a match pattern found

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
>cat file1.txt
aa bb
ccc dd
ee fff
>cat file2.txt
1
2
3
```

I want to get the result like below:

```
aa1bb
ccc2dd
ee3fff
```

The space in file1.txt will be replaced by number in file2.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward way by `awk`,

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{sub(/\ /,a[FNR])}1' file2 file1
aa1bb
ccc2dd
ee3fff
```

Brief explanation,

- `NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}`: store each record in file2 to array a
- `sub(/\ /,a[FNR])`: substitute the space by `a[FNR]` in file2, where FNR would be the record number in the file2.
- Appended `1`would print each processed line in file2

Comment: Thanks for your help ~

Answer (score 3):

**`paste`** + **`awk`** approach:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{ print $1$3$2 }'
```

The output:

```
aa1bb
ccc2dd
ee3fff
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$ paste <(cut -d " " -f1 file1.txt) file2.txt <(cut -d " " -f2 file1.txt) | tr -d $'\t'
aa1bb
ccc2dd
ee3fff
```

Comment: If you use `paste -d "" ...` you can drop the pipe to `tr`

Answer (score 0):

with a bash while-read loop

```
while read -u3 a b; read -u4 n; do 
    echo "$a$n$b"
done 3<file1.txt 4<file2.txt
```